# multiple plots with checkboxes

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm currently using matplotlib.figure so that I can have two plots side by side, and then a table right below. One of the plots is a set of linear regressions, and the other is e^(linear regressions).
I would like to use matplotlib widgets CheckButtons in addition to this so that way if I have 3 data sets I have the option to display just 2 or just 1 of them at a time. I've been having a hard time getting both of these to play nicely together, any suggestions?

edit:
here is the code I am using now

It's initiated by calling plot. Curve is an array of the form [[m1,b1],[m2,b2],etc.] xdata is an array of the form [xdata(dataset1),xdata(dataset2),xdata(dataset3),etc.] ydata is self explanatory. ydatalin is the same data but after we transform the exponential data to fit a line.

````
from tkinter import Tk
from math import exp
from math import log as ln
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def logc(time,c0,k): #takes exponential and converts it to line
    def f1(t):
        return -k*t+ln(c0)
    return list(map(f1,time))

def concentration(time,k,c0): #takes line and converts it to exponential
    def f1(t):
        return c0*exp(-k*t)
    return list(map(f1,time))

def plot_one(coeff, xdata, ydata, ylindata, plt1, plt2, colorr, trial):#create a single plot to be combined with other plots
    xpointscurve = np.linspace(0, max(xdata), 10000)
    ypointscurve = concentration(xpointscurve, coeff[1], coeff[0])

    xdata.append(0)  # force plot range to be 0 to max(xdata), instead of the range of xdata
    logcc = logc(xdata, *coeff)
    plt1.plot(xdata, logcc, color=colorr)

    xdata.pop(-1)
    plt1.plot(xdata, ylindata, '.', color=colorr,label=trial)
    plt1.legend()

    plt2.plot(xpointscurve, ypointscurve, color=colorr)
    plt2.plot(xdata, ydata, '.', color=colorr,label=trial)
    plt2.legend()
    
def plot(curve,xdata,ydata,ylindata):
    #main output
    
    matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')
    colors=['b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w']
    if(len(xdata)>len(colors)):
        for i in range(len(xdata)-len(colors)):
            colors.append(matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv([random(),random(),random()]))
            
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5),tight_layout=True)
    plt1=plt.subplot(221)
    plt2=plt.subplot(222)
    tab=plt.subplot(212)



    
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

    rows=[]
    hls=[]
    output=[]
    
    for i in range(len(xdata)):
        rows.append('trial %d:' % (i+1) )
        plot_one(curve[i],xdata[i],ydata[i],ylindata[i],plt1,plt2,colors[i],rows[i])
       


    plt.show()```
````

Comment: please, provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Just edited it to include the code I am using now, this is as far as I could trim it down while still working as desired.